# JCombobox not refreshing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, observable

Hi i have two class Banque and Succursale, Bank has a list of Succursale and each time that list changes i want Succursale to get it and then using it to refresh the JCombobox of its view, problem is that the JComboBox is not refreshing while its item count is incrementing, here are the class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;


public class Banque extends Observable {
private List<Succursale> listSucc = new ArrayList<Succursale>();
private int sommeTotale;
private int nbSuccInit = 4;

public void ajouteSucc(Succursale suc){

}
public Banque(){
    initialiserServeur();       
}
private void initialiserServeur() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
    try { 
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10118); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("On ne peut pas ecouter au  port: 10118."); 
        System.exit(1); 
    }
    System.out.println ("Le serveur est en marche, Attente de la connexion.....");
    int i = 0;
    while(i<5){
        try {
            UtilMultiTh mt = new UtilMultiTh(serverSocket.accept());
            Thread t = new Thread(mt);
            t.start();
            t.join();
            Succursale s = mt.getSuc();
            listSucc.add(s);
            this.addObserver(s);
            this.setChanged();
            this.notifyObservers(this.listSucc);

            //System.out.println(listSucc.size());

           /* for(int j =0; j<listSucc.size();j++){
                System.out.println("La succursale "+(j+1)+" est:"+listSucc.get(j).getName());
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println("FLAGPOSTban");*/
        } 
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) 
        { 
            System.err.println("Accept a echoue."); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 
    }


    System.out.println ("connexion reussie");
    System.out.println ("Attente de l'entree.....");

}

public static void main (String [] args){
    Banque banK = new Banque();
}
}
```

The class Succursale

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;


public class Succursale implements Serializable, Observer {
private String coordonnees;
private String name;
private int sommeDepart;
private int sommeRecue;
private int sommeEnvoyee;
private List<Succursale> listSuccAc = new ArrayList<Succursale>();
private GuiSuccursale succView;

public Succursale (){
    succView = new GuiSuccursale(Constantes.sommeDepart,1);
    this.sommeDepart=Constantes.sommeDepart;
    this.name="Succursale: "+(1);
    connexionBanque();
}
public void connexionBanque(){
    String host = Constantes.adrBanque[0];
    int port = Constantes.portBanque[0];
    Socket echoSocket = null;
    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket(host, port);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(this);
        //System.out.println("FLAGPOSTSUcc");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Hôte inconnu: " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Ne pas se connecter au serveur: " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
public void connexionSuccursales(){

}
public void envoiManuel(){

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void envoiPeriodique(){

}
public static void main (String[] args){
    Succursale suc = new Succursale();
}
@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    this.listSuccAc= (List)arg1;
    this.succView.setListeSucc(listSuccAc);
    //this.succView.validate();
    //System.out.println("Mes succ connectees sont:"+this.listSuccAc.size());
    //System.out.println("Mes succ connectees sont:"+this.getName());

}
}
```

and the view of Succursale

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GuiSuccursale extends JFrame{

private JLabel labelSum = new JLabel("Montant:");
private JIntField champMontant = new JIntField(0, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
private JLabel labelSumDispo = new JLabel ("Somme Disponible");
private JIntField champSumDispo;
private JLabel labelSucc = new JLabel("Vers la Succursale:");
private ComboBoxModel cbm;
private JComboBox listeSucc = new JComboBox<>();
private JPanel pan = new JPanel();
private JButton btnTransferer = new JButton("Transferer");
private JButton btnEffacer = new JButton("Effacer");
public  GuiSuccursale(int sumDepart, int num){
    init(sumDepart, num);
}
public void init(int sumDepart, int num){

    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
    gl.setColumns(2);
    gl.setRows(4);
    gl.setHgap(5);
    gl.setVgap(5);
    pan.setLayout(gl);

    labelSumDispo.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    labelSumDispo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));

    champSumDispo = new JIntField(sumDepart, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    champSumDispo.setEditable(false);

    labelSucc.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    labelSucc.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));

    labelSum.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    labelSum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));


    pan.add(labelSumDispo);
    pan.add(champSumDispo);
    pan.add(labelSucc);
    pan.add(listeSucc);
    pan.add(labelSum);
    pan.add(champMontant);
    pan.add(btnTransferer);
    pan.add(btnEffacer);

    this.setContentPane(pan);
    this.setSize(300, 150);
    this.setTitle("Succursale: "+num);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
public JComboBox getListeSucc() {
    return listeSucc;
}
public void setListeSucc(List<Succursale> listeSucc) {
    this.listeSucc.removeAllItems();
    for(int i = 0; i<listeSucc.size();i++){
        System.out.println("l<index est:"+i);

        this.listeSucc.addItem(listeSucc.get(i).getName());
        System.out.println(this.listeSucc.getItemCount());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what model in combobox are you using?? sysout works fine? call revalidate, wrap calls in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: i am not using a model, i use the JComboBox directly

Comment: Try to use `listeSucc.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(listeSucc));` in your `setListeSucc()` method.

Comment: I did so but still nothing.